# Custom UserAuthenticationConverter in Oauth ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I need to use custom UserAuthenticationConverter implementation to extract custom Authentication objects.

I used the following way:

I at first created bean for my access converter with required UserAuthenticationConverter implementation.

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenEnhancer() {
    final JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    final DefaultAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    tokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(new CustomUserConverter());
    jwtConverter.setAccessTokenConverter(tokenConverter);
    return jwtConverter;
}
```

And after that I set to original RemoteTokenServices that converter.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RemoteTokenServices customRemoteTokenService(RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices) 
{
    remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(tokenEnhancer());
    return remoteTokenServices;
}
```

I want to ask if this is the correct way to achieve that, or there is a better or recommended way? Thank you.